# File Transfer , onProgress not working on iOS ( IONIC3 )

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I been working with fileTransfer from Ionic native, it working fine on Android, but on iOS not not do anything at all

Here is my code:

```
getFile(fileName,url){   
      let fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
      fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + fileName).then((entry) => { 
        console.log('entry:',entry)   
      }, (error) => { console.log(error); });   
      console.log('file transfer',fileTransfer.onProgress) 
     var a = fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent: ProgressEvent) => { 
        this.ngzone.run(() => {   
          console.log(progressEvent.loaded)
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: There is a good example in this repo for getting fileTransfer to work for iOS: https://github.com/dtaalbers/ionic-example-app. I followed this example and it worked. This issue has something to do with scoping.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how to derive this.file.dataDirectory.

In my case it always works like this ..

```
declare var cordova:any; //on top of file

if (this.platform.is('android')) {
    this.fsurl = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
}else{
    this.fsurl = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
}
```

Comment: hello @enRaiser , thank you for your help, but it still not work on iOS, the file transfer is fine, buy I want to show it progress, how many percentage or file size does it downloaded. It work fine on Android but, iOS not show anything at all